# Material-ui - Treeview Expand all

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui/lab 4.0.0-alpha.27 - TreeView Component

I have a treeview with a couple of hundred nodes. I have added a textfield before the treview that the user can use to search/filter the tree. As they type I add/remove classes from the TreeItems to hide and show TreeItems. It works fine BUT we want all of the nodes to be expanded once they enter something into the search/filter textfield.

I have tried feeding the "defaultExpanded" prop a new list that has all of the nodes in it but it doesn't seem to cause the nodes to expand as I had expected. The defaultExpanded prop only seems to be respected when the tree initially draws.

I am currently working around this by looking for collapsed nodes and firing click events for them to force them to open but that is causing issues (the textfield looses focus and the keyboard hides and the treeview jumps around). I need something a bit smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `expanded` prop, instead of `defaultExpanded`.